# Pass user credentials to JSP website from SharePoint website

Tags: development, web-part, web-services, visual-web-part

I have developed a JSP website. I also have a SharePoint server based website.

Let's call my JSP website to be www.xyzjsp.com and my SharePoint based website to be www.mySPwebsite.com

How can I created a login form on www.mySPwebsite.com and want to login into www.xyzjsp.com.

Is it possible to send those data from www.mySPwebsite.com to www.xyzjsp.com so that when data is received by the JSP site from that SP site it logs user in.

Or if this is not possible, then is there any alternate to achieve this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that can be effectively done in custom code by an average developer.  What you really want to do is establish a Single-Sign-On solution.  This can be done with a packaged SSO solution from vendors like Microsoft, Oracle, or F5.

Alternatively, it is possible to share some basic authentication info for the session by setting both systems up to use ADFS since the claim is accessible from the client machine.